# Rails cambiar estado de un ítem true a false

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo un modelo **Equipment** donde hay un campo que se llama *Availability* que es boolean ,y necesito que cuando un usuario que está previamente logueado seleccione un equipo, automáticamente el equipo pase a no estar disponible si otro usuario quisiera escogerlo. Lo que estoy haciendo es control y prestamos de equipos de computo, entonces si un usuario solicita un equipo, este mismo equipo no puede solicitarlo otro usuario hasta que el usuario inicial que pidió el equipo lo devuelva. Principalmente necesito saber como hago para pasar el campo **availability** que esta *true* a *false* cuando un usuario selecciona el equipo. Muchas gracias.

Tengo el siguiente formulario donde el usuario solicita el equipo:

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <%= form.label :return %>
  <%= form.datetime_select :return %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :Equipo, class: "control-label" %><br>
  <%= form.collection_select(:equipment_id, Equipment.all, :id, :name, prompt: "Seleccione un equipo") %>
  <br><br>
</div>  

<div class="actions">
  <%= form.submit %>
</div>
```

Este es el schema donde se ven las tablas users, loans(pedidos) y equipment

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Kamiro, bienvenido a S.O. en español. Por lo que explicas, tienes la idea clara de lo que se requiere, solo necesitas hacer las vistas y controladores que manejen eso.¿qué código has realizado? ¿que te funciona?¿qué no? En gral. las preguntas realizadas aquí son de problemas específicos y puntuales que tengas, revisa [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para tener una idea más clara y puedas editar la pregunta para recibir más ayuda de la comunidad. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esa lógica yo la manejaría en el modelo de Loan.
En un `before_create` haces que el self.equipment.availability = true y con eso ya se cambia el valor.
Y para revisar que el equipo no este ya rentado en el modelo de Loan haz un custom validation donde revises que availability del equipo sea == false.

Aquí puedes leer más sobre el before_create:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Aquí puedes leer más sobre las validaciones:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias, necesitaba una guía para poder seguir, estaba la verdad un poco estancado muchísimas gracias